# Schemas and user permissions

Tags: sql-server, schema, permissions, users

When our custom, home-grown CMS creates data tables using the GUI, it creates them against the site-specific user schema (i.e. `sitename`) instead of the `dbo` schema.

The issue is that our site-specific users currently do not "see" these other schemas even though they are in the `db_owner` role. So somewhere there is a permissions setting missing which would grant them the ability to read and write against those tables.

This issue has occurred when migrating to a new SQL server. Going from 2005 Workgroup Edition to 2008 Web Edition.

Answer (score 5):

It could be as simple as:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::[sitename] TO [user];
```

If there are procedures and functions you will also need:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[sitename] TO [user];
```

The full list of permissions applicable at the schema level is listed in the documentation:

- [GRANT Schema Permissions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187940.aspx)

You can also set the default schema for any user, which may be helpful in some scenarios (for example, if *they* create tables without explicitly specifying the `sitename` schema):

```
ALTER USER [user] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [sitename];
```

Note that `DENY` overrides `GRANT` (and also overrides role membership rights, including `db_owner`), so check to be sure someone hasn't inadvertently *blocked* access to the schema(s). You can start your investigation if you find any rows here:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_permissions
  WHERE class_desc = N'SCHEMA' AND [state] = 'D';
```

Note that permissions can apply to a user indirectly (e.g. through AD group membership or database roles), so make sure you follow the bread crumbs for *any* database principal with a relevant `DENY`...